# Scriptable menu bar icons

Tags: applescript, menu-bar, customization

Is there an easy way I can add custom icons to the menu bar status area? Ideally something like Growl (e.g., where you can just execute a command) but instead of notifications, just renders icons in the menu bar.

I'm mainly looking to draw numbers that I'd use to alert me of various things. For example, I can configure my email client to run a command/AppleScript to update the numbers when an certain kind of email arrives.

Something like this:

[image: img]

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest starting with [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5883495), which describes using Cocoa Objective-C calls from within AppleScript. There is an example Xcode project [here](http://www.menace-enterprises.com/Files/AppleScriptObjC/Examples/Conversion%20-%20Menulet.zip).

And [Launch](http://www.hanken.co.uk/launch/) is a complete application written in AppleScript that functionally does this. Its Xcode project file is [here](http://www.hanken.co.uk/launch/Launch.zip).

The basic premise is to generate NSMenuItem instances and add them to the system's NSStatusBar:

```
set statusMenu to (NSMenu's alloc)'s initWithTitle_("Launch")
-- (build and do stuff with the statusMenu here)
set sysStatusBar to NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar
set statusItem to sysStatusBar's statusItemWithLength_(32)
tell statusItem to setMenu_(statusMenu)
tell statusItem to setHighlightMode_(1)
set menuImage to NSImage's imageNamed_("icon.png")
tell statusItem to setImage_(menuImage)
```

<sub>*AppleScript excerpt from Launch's source code, Copyright © Lee Hanken*</sub>

Comment: Links are missing now in 2018

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I have made an app for this. It is on GitHub: [0942v8653/ScriptableStatusBar](https://github.com/0942v8653/ScriptableStatusBar). Just keep the app running and use the `sbar` tool to set and remove items.

As the readme says:

```
sbar set face  'Bye!:sbar remove face'
```

Creates a face in the status bar. The menu will have an option `Bye!` that runs `sbar remove face` getting rid of the menu it creates.

---

You can download a compiled version from https://github.com/0942v8653/ScriptableStatusBar/releases.

Comment: Nice, but why do You register to all distributed notifications instead of the one with name: "io.github.0942v8653.ScriptableStatusBar"?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Good question. Will fix later :P

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Fixed.

Comment: Your app's functionality seems to be very similar to "BitBar" (mentioned above); while yours features an icon (not sure if BitBar does), the other allows  nearly any scripting language (with std-out) to very easily display its output in the right-hand menu bar. I use that to "osascript" an apple script that "returns" the current number of workspace I'm on (like in former OS versions). Scripts are simply placed into a plugin folder & EXTRA! part of names (e.g. xx.3s.sh => 3 seconds) specifies repetition intervals. VERY useful for status displaying !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [RubyCocoa](http://rubycocoa.sourceforge.net/):

```
require "osx/cocoa"
include OSX

app = NSApplication.sharedApplication
statusitem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(NSVariableStatusItemLength)
statusitem.setTitle("aa")
app.run
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Rumps, a Python library that uses the Obj-C classes and functions.

http://rumps.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a Cocoa app for this purpose in Xcode. No, you cannot do it with applescript.

Answer (score 0):

## [xbar](https://xbarapp.com/)

[xbar](https://xbarapp.com/dl) (download link) allows you to add a large number of plug-ins and menus to the macOS menu bar.

There are already pre-built plugins available, but you can also create your own if you want to.

For help with scripting plugins, have a look at the [Writing plugins guide](https://github.com/matryer/xbar-plugins/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md).